# Excel VBA - Is there a TextChanging / TextChanged or a similar event? Or how to move a selection without using Enter?

Tags: windows, events, vba, excel

I have recently been asked if I could make a macro in Excel VBA that will allow a user to type in two numbers and have it automatically drop to the next row. The purpose of this is so they can type in grades for a test two numbers at a time without pressing enter since they aren't great at typing.

When I first heard this he mentioned it was Visual Basic, so I figured I'd just use a TextChanging or TextChanged event in the cell range and have it work off that. However, I haven't been able to find any such event or anything resembling it in the documentation thus far. The first thing that I came across was Workbook_Change, but that only changes after you press enter which is useless to me. Someone else mentioned there is such an event, but couldn't name it directly and I haven't been able to find what they were talking about.

If anyone has any information on if such an event exists or is possible I'd love to know.

The Excel version is 2007 as far as I'm aware.

Comment: How bad can a person be at typing that they can't press enter after entering digits?! Seriously though I don't think it is possible to trigger a `worksheet event` without actually keying enter. Perhaps if all the data is in a userform opposed to the worksheet it might be possible..

Comment: He's a really old man, so I just think it would be easier for him to not have to hassle with it. I watched him use the computer a few weeks ago and he's terribly slow at it. He needs this to key in grades for his calculus classes since the math hall got cuts in the test department.

Comment: Ok fair enough, if this were possible what if he accidentally types a wrong number? He'd then have to go back and edit which would probably be more challenging than making sure it's correct before entering?

Comment: @AlistairWeir try my solution, I was suprised, but I think in some cases this could really ease up specific work. You can type realy fast on a num pad i.e. and using the right arrow to go to the next data. On error, you just go up or up and right to correct yourself. quite nice :)

Comment: I like the user form idea. He clicks a button, it opens a user form with a big textbox and a `Done` button. you can capture key presses in the textbox. Every two characters on a line print a `vbNewLine`. Then when he's done he presses `Done` and you real the textbox's lines array (might need to make that array on your own by splitting on new lines, I forget how the object is set up). Then write to whatever cell needs to be written into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, in my opinion, requires a non-programming solution. I absolutely sympathize - it is tough to watch people get old - but you have to draw the line somewhere - for their sake and yours. The enter key is the most basic part of a computer. You could probably write a macro that would automatically hit enter on every even(or odd depending) keystroke in excel - but you're going to run into other problems like not being able to use delete normally. And what if you do want to put a string of text in a cell(like the student's name)? Perhaps it is time to find a non-programming solution. By that I mean someone should have a candid conversation with him about how he wants to solve the problem. Personally, I would offer to type the numbers in for him, as I am accustomed to the number pad - but it is probably better to be more direct and start to discuss retirement.

See this discussion about the limitations of cell edit mode in excel:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524860-call-macro-every-keystroke.html

If you're really heart-set on a programming solution, I would recommend some kind of keystroke logging add-in.

Good Luck.

Comment: I'm in no position to tell him to retire as he is a very good teacher. However, you're right on the point that VBA can't do this as far as I've been told so far. I'll mark this as the accepted answer unless something comes up.

Comment: Yea, like I said it kind of depends on your approach for handling the situation. Me personally, I would try to find a personable way to solve the problem - like offering to type in the numbers for him. So I am just trying to discuss the issue holistically. Their are people who are horrible with computers who are awesome at their jobs(including teachers) - but oftentimes these problems can be general signs of old age. At which point it is time to enjoy retirement - You've worked your whole life!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.  It is triggered without enter, but it would be triggered a lot.

You could however also create a special user-form for typing in the data, but this might be more work than necessary.

The main problem with using my suggested event is, you will need it as trigger and trigger it yourself, when selecting the next row, so disable event handling before changing the selection.

---

Edit:

This is a quick solution (paste this into the vba-code of the desired worksheet):

```
Private Const clngColumnRightToLastGrade = 5

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = clngColumnRightToLastGrade Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'offset selection, one row down, two cols to left
    Target.Offset(1, -2).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

This will set you one row down and to column C, everytime your selection changes to column E (`=5`).

You don't have to use a constant of course, you could specify the column to sense in the workbook, so your user might modify it easier by himself.

To make this as an optional feature, you could extend it to autogenerated code. What I have in mind is like a Ribbon-Button, which opens a setupForm to configure, and a Ribbon-Button to activate the configuration, which would place this code in the configured sheet. But this might be a bit over the top.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I needed. I don't think it should be firing on selection change since you'd have to press enter or move cells to have that event fire. I conclude from your code that you expected two numbers in two different cells, but I'm talking about two numbers (I guess vaguely) as something like 89. Each of them would be a grade which he said would always be two numbers. My logic (before I ran into the event shortage trouble) was check the text of the current cell after every keypress (TextChanging/TextChanged event) and check the length of the text.

Comment: oh, ok, misunderstood you - but I would nearly bet that there is no way to catch an inprogress edit of a cell - I don't fear messy solutions, but this feels so bad, not even MS thought of that. If it is even to much to use the arrows, you will need a UserForm or to follow Stepan1010 suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2003, (may be different in Excel2007 ?!) the WorkSheet_Change event is triggered every time the value of a cell is changed wether it is by pressing enter, delete, selecting an other cell after modifying a cell or even when a vba script changes the value of a cell.

I would do something like that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RefRange As Range
    Set RefRange = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("??????????"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Not Intersect(Target, RefRange) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Range("A1").Select
        'Target.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but the problem here is in the event itself. I need the event to fire without enter, changing cell, or selecting something else. It should move by itself once a 2-digit number is entered.

Comment: You could create a UserForm and use the KeyDown event then

Comment: Actually, you cannot run any VBA script while Excel is in Edit mode (editing a value from a cell). Thus the only solutions would be thru education or a UserForm Keystroke Event... I think you have just hit a limit of what VBA programmation can do. Plus, by doing a Userform, you would give the feeling that you did even more that what they asked !!